# PHP/SQL/AJAX Checkbox not being serialised despite adding hidden input

Tags: php, sql, ajax, forms, checkbox

I am trying to create a form where a client can check off their tasks that automatically saves (AJAX). When the client checks the form, the value of the task's ID is sent to the PHP page. However, if the client unchecks it, even with the exact same code, the value disappears and I don't understand why. Here is my code:

`index.php`

```
<form method="post" action="this.form.submit();" name="form1">
  <div class="client-list">
    <div class="checkbox-list">

       <?php if(empty($clientTask['status'])): ?>
          <input type="checkbox" id="task0" name="task0" onclick="function1();" value="1">
       <?php else: ?>
          <input type="checkbox" id="task0" name="task0" onclick="function1();" value="1" checked>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <label for="task0">Task 0 Name</label>

       <?php if(empty($clientTask['status'])): ?>
          <input type="checkbox" id="task1" name="task1" onclick="function1();" value="2">
       <?php else: ?>
          <input type="checkbox" id="task1" name="task1" onclick="function1();" value="2" checked>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <label for="task1">Task 1 Name</label>

       <?php if(empty($clientTask['status'])): ?>
          <input type="checkbox" id="task2" name="task2" onclick="function1();" value="3">
       <?php else: ?>
          <input type="checkbox" id="task2" name="task2" onclick="function1();" value="3" checked>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <label for="task2">Task 2 Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

`script.js`

```
<script>
    function function1() {
    var data = $("[name='form1']").serialize()
    $.ajax({
        url: "client-tasks.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: data, 
        success: function(data){ 
            alert(data) 
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I tried 3 different ways to see what works and what doesn't in `client-tasks.php`:

1. `$_POST['task0']` works both ways when the `id` is hard-coded.
2. `$_POST['task1']` only works in the `if` statement, but the value disappears in the `else` statement. It doesn't matter if the `status` is set to `1` or `0`.
3. The whole code with `$_POST['task2']` will work even though the `$task2` is an empty string.

From what I found, the `else` statement never works unless it is hard-coded. So, I need to find a way to get it working.

```
<?php
   include("../../path.php");
   include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/database/config.php");
   

    if (isset($_POST['task0'])) {
        $sql1="UPDATE client_tasks SET status = 1 WHERE id = 1";        
    } else {
        $sql1="UPDATE client_tasks SET status = 0 WHERE id = 1";
    }
    $result=$conn->query($sql1);
  
    if (isset($_POST['task1'])) {
        $sql2="UPDATE client_tasks SET status = 1 WHERE id = " . $_POST['task1'] . "";
    } else {
        $sql2="UPDATE client_tasks SET status = 0 WHERE id = " . $_POST['task1'] . "";
    }
    $result=$conn->query($sql2);

    $task2 = $_POST['task2'];
    if (isset(task2)) {
        $sql3="UPDATE client_tasks SET status = 1 WHERE id = " . $task2 . "";
    } else {
        $sql3="UPDATE client_tasks SET status = 0 WHERE id = '$task2'";
    }
    $result=$conn->query($sql3);
```

[When it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF1KE.png)
[When it doesn't work (empty string helps execute code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6EkU.png)

I would really appreciate any help or advice, thank you!

Comment: Another really old trick is to add an hidden input before every checkbox with the _un-checked_ value... `<input type="hidden" name="task0" value="0" />`

Comment: I'm fairly certain your issue is that an unchecked checkbox does not send any value to a server, whereas a checked checkbox does. An unchecked checkbox is also not serialized, and nothing is received by PHP.

Comment: @Phil I was just about to say the exact same thing.

Comment: Please also familiarise yourself with prepared statements. [This MySQLi tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli) is highly recommended (or the [PDO equivalent](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) if that's what you're using)

Comment: You could cut down on a lot of boilerplate by simply using `$checked = !empty($clientTask['status']) ? ' checked' : '';` and `<input ... <?= $checked ?>>`

Comment: @Jacob I agree, but I am not sure how to serialise it.

Comment: @Phil I tried your hidden input trick, but it won't let me check or uncheck at all. I will though definitely introduce prepared statements, thank you for that advice. The cutting down works, so also thank you.

Comment: I was also testing to see if the value works in the `console.log()` and it works fine, it's just not being sent to the PHP file

Comment: @CaitlinO One option might be using JavaScript to "check" the hidden checkbox when the user unselects the corresponding visible checkbox and posting that to your PHP script. Of course the hidden checkbox would actually be checked, but it would be labelled to identify that it is representing the "unchecked" value of the initial checkbox. This might be useful: [check other checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62521304/checking-other-checkboxes-when-i-select-a-checkbox-not-a-select-all-checkbox?rq=2)

Comment: @CaitlinO In response to your comment "I tried your hidden in....won't let me check or uncheck at all", you could try setting the value of the checkbox to 1, which PHP would receive as a boolean value (true or false), or you could try using other css styling to hide the checkbox without using the input attribute. **Edit:** I now realize that the hidden checkbox Phil mentioned is not a checkbox but a hidden input, alternatively you could use a hidden checkbox: `<input type="checkbox" name="unchecked_task0" value="1" style="display:none !important" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off">`